# Installing IIS after .NET Framework

Tags: visual-studio, iis, .net-3.5

I already have installed visual studio 2008.After that i installed IIS.so how can i configure IIS to work with .NET

Answer (score 5):

Run [Aspnet_regiis.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(VS.90).aspx)